# Index Match; Array with Numbers & Text; Find Value bigger & smaller than

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking to find the values which are bigger than 1 and smaller than 100 in an array with Numbers and Text.

Example of the table:

[image: TABLE 1]

The goal is to extract Column F values only where the numbers match the conditions (i.e. >1 & <100).

Answer (score 1):

As long as there's only one matching value in each row, a `SUMIFS` will work

```
=SUMIFS(A2:E2,A2:E2,">1",A2:E2,"<100")
```